# $wp_query->max_num_pages not working for CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

am implementing custom pagination for my CPT products. Here what i tried
-- in taxonomy-product-category.php

```
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'parent' => 0,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array($term->slug),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
        ),
    ); 
?>
```

in functions.php

```
 function get_pagination($range = 4) {
    global $paged, $wp_query;
    $no_of_posts = 6;
    // How much pages do we have?
    if (!$max_page) {
        $max_page = round($wp_query->max_num_pages / $no_of_posts);
    }
    die($wp_query->max_num_pages);
}
```

But the issue is

```
if (!$max_page) {
    $max_page = round($wp_query->max_num_pages / $no_of_posts);
}
die($wp_query->max_num_pages);
```

For this it is always returning $wp_query->max_num_pages always returning 1.I don't want to divide it by number of posts .

Comment: do you have any other filters that might distrupt this ? for example `add_action('pre_get_posts', 'some_function');` ? also, does the return value is always the same ( single, archives ) ?

Comment: yeah  i used this

Comment: function custom_posts_per_page($query) {
    //fixing pagination of custom post type
    if ($query->is_archive('products')) {
        set_query_var('posts_per_page', 1);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page');

Comment: Try to remove or change value or change priority and see the effect.

Comment: ok thanks I removed it and all worked.

Comment: ok, great. But if you did not write this filter yourself ( e.g. - you know what you are doing ) do not just remove the filter because it can cause other issues. Also - I added it also as an answer so you could accept to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a few issues that can cause this but let's start with the most frequent one:

You probably have some other filter that intervene with the query in early stage, something like:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'some_function');
```

or any other function that alters the query. 
Try to remove / change priority and see results but stay alert because this `pre_get_post` action might be neccessary / usefull for other things, so be sure you know what you are doing..